# Ajax request ERROR on IE

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a small problem on IE browser (actually on Google Chrome too)
I have this js code

```
function createDoc(url) {
    var xhttp = ajaxRequest();
    var currentLocationBase = window.location.href;
    currentLocationBase = currentLocationBase.substr(0,currentLocationBase.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
    var u  = currentLocationBase + url;

    xhttp.open("GET", u, false);
    xhttp.send(null);

    var xml = xhttp.responseXML;
    return xml;
}

/**
* Builds an AJAX reques handler.
*
* @return The handler.
*/
function ajaxRequest() {
    var xhttp = null;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else if (window.ActiveXObject){     
        // Internet Explorer 5/6
        xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    } else {
    }
    return xhttp;
}
```

In Firefox this code works great, but not in IE and Google Chrome
Seems that the error is given at the line

```
xhttp.open("GET", u, false);
```

Can anyone help me to understand what i'm doing wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the Ajax is async you need to handle the code and response in the onreadystatechange code. Try [w3schools examples](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp)

It looks like you are sending the request and just after that reading the responseXML, this must be causing problems

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax_info.txt",true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you deploy jQuery? Comes with optimised [AJAX stack](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/) and no need to do browser-specific sniffing. You'd indeed hit more app weight over library inclusion, but it's surely well worth it.

Comment: I don't want to add any framework library. It's an application who need to be created only by me.